# Django-Allauth and facebook URL Blocked challenge

Tags: facebook-login, django-allauth

I have been through the allauth setup, using default settings, and solved problems like the https issue::

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"

DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"
```

And using ngrok so that I can access my development environment using::

```
https://7fff461c.ngrok.io/  (not real code)
```

And checking that the full callback works::

```
https://7fff461c.ngrok.io/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
```

And settings up Facebook with Valid OAuth Redirect URIs set to https://7fff461c.ngrok.io/ so when I enter https://7fff461c.ngrok.io in the Redirect URI Validator at the bottom of the facebook page it works...

When I try to signup link I get an error from facebook:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

Doubled check that the redirect url being passed is correct, which it is::

decoded:  &redirect_uri=https://7fff461c.ngrok.io/accounts/facebook/login/callback/&scop

What else is there to try?!

Comment: thanks for tidying Ahmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, but I'll leave this question/answer here in case it helps anyone else.

When putting in the the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in Facebook Login > settings it needs THE WHOLE URL!

So in this case:

```
https://7fff461c.ngrok.io/accounts/facebook/login/callback/
```

Now it's all working.